# Unable to store and retrieve JSON value by JQUERY

Tags: json, performance, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have two textbox(goalText and goalText1) and a button(goalreach) in my html. 
My aim : When I enter numeric value in 1 textbox(goalText), it should be converted to json and be stored. So even after 5 days when I run the application, it should be stored. Now when I enter the numeric value, in other textbox(goalText1) and it matches, I am simply displaying the message match. This is the demo, I am trying so that I can know that value can be stored in json and can be retrieved when necessary. I have written the code as follow:

```
$("#goalreach").click(function () {
  var contact = new Object();
  contact.goalDist = "$("#goalText.value ").val()";
  var jsonText = JSON.stringify(contact);
  if (jsonText == ($("#goalText1.value").val())) {
      document.getElementById('divid').innerHTML = 'Match';
  }
});
```

I know, I have made many simple mistakes of brackets and  " too, but I am a newbie, If you can help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have to compare either 2 objects or 2 strings, and in `goalDist`, you should store the value (BTW, you get the jQuery object with `$("#goalText")` and the value with `somejQueryObject.val()` moreover this is generally equivalent to `document.getElementById("goalText").value`)...

This can be done like this :

```
$("#goalreach").click(function () {
  // Create an object with the single property "goalDist"
  var contact = { goalDist : $("#goalText").val() };

  // Makes it be a string (it will in this simple example : `"{"goalDist":<the value of goalTest>}"`
  var jsonText = JSON.stringify(contact);

  // Creates a string from an equivalent object bound on the second field
  var jsonText2 = JSON.stringify({ goalDist : $("#goalText2").val() });

  // Compares the 2 strings
  if (jsonText === jsonText2) {
      document.getElementById('divid').innerHTML = 'Match';
  }
});
```

Comment: I don't know, why everybody's code is not working. Am I making any silly mistake ? The id of my div is "divid", Is .innerHTML line correct ?
I am writing it in a javascript. And in the html file, I have added the source of this js, I think I am correct in other things.

Comment: I have made some jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/SFGmS/. You can test the code. Javascript is case sensitive : be careful of the ids in your HTML code...

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
$("#goalreach").click(function () {
    var contact = new Object();
    contact.goalDist = $("#goalText").val();
    var jsonText = JSON.stringify(contact);
    if (jsonText == ($("#goalText1").val())) {
        document.getElementById('divid').innerHTML = 'Match';
    }
});
```

OR

```
$("#goalreach").click(function () {
    var goalText = $("#goalText").val();
    var goalText1 = $("#goalText1").val();
    if (goalText == goalText1) {
        document.getElementById('divid').innerHTML = 'Match';
    }
});
```

Comment: make sure that your taxtbox has the id attribute which is used in jquery.

Comment: <input type="text" id="goalText" style="width:150px" />


<input type="text" id="goalText1" style="width:150px" />

Comment: Not getting any error, but samuels code worked. I think, I would need to compare two objects only ?? I am unable to get,,why your code is not working.

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS

```
$("#goalreach").click(function () {

var contact = new Object();

var goalDist  = '$("#goalText.value").val()';
var jsonText = JSON.stringify(contact.goalDist);

if(jsonText==($("#goalText1.value").val()))
{
     document.getElementById('divid').innerHTML = 'Match';
}
});
```